# Array subscripting and pointer arithmetics in C give different result

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

I am getting different memory address (invalid one) when trying to obtain the address of the value located inside of an array when using array subscript syntax as opposed to when using pointer arithmetic which indeed yields expected (correct) memory address.
Why is that?

This code was compiled with gcc C99 and C11, flags: -Wall -O0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int arg = 0;
    char         arr[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    char*        arrp   = arr + 2;
    char*        pos_1  = arrp - arg - 1;
    char*        pos_2  = &arrp[-arg - 1];
    printf("arr:  %p\narrp: %p\npos_1:%p\npos_2:%p\n", arr, arrp, pos_1, pos_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
arr:  0x7fff31035a73
arrp: 0x7fff31035a75
pos_1:0x7fff31035a74
pos_2:0x800031035a74
```

`pos_2` is invalid as you can see.

But when using a constant `0` as opposed to a variable `arg` I get the correct memory address for `pos_2` also...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char         arr[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    char*        arrp   = arr + 2;
    char*        pos_1  = arrp - 0 - 1;
    char*        pos_2  = &arrp[-0 - 1];
    printf("arr:  %p\narrp: %p\npos_1:%p\npos_2:%p\n", arr, arrp, pos_1, pos_2);
    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
arr:  0x7ffc270c4ed3
arrp: 0x7ffc270c4ed5
pos_1:0x7ffc270c4ed4
pos_2:0x7ffc270c4ed4
```

which is correct (compiled second time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `arg` is `unsigned`, `-arg - 1` makes an `unsigned` with the value `UINT_MAX` (`0u - 1` "wrapps around" and becomes the largest possible `unsigned`) - which is out of bounds of pretty much any array.

`-0 - 1` is on the other hand done using `int`s and the result is `-1`.

Comment: Oh god...such a rookie mistake, thanks.

Comment: @Newb It's an easy mistake to make! You're welcome!